# Pass back Tableview Cell Data to filter objects in my PFQueryTableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` which lists films. In my navigation bar, I have a filter button, which when the user presses it, it displays a `UIPopoverPresentationController`. This popover simply displays some options in a UITableView. See the image below:

[image]

**Goal**

When the user selects an option in the popover, I need the option index to be passed back to the main `PFQueryTableViewController` and then update the table accordingly. And to also close the popover controller.

I already know how I can sort the table, I just need to know how to pass the selected option back, and then how to add it into the `if` statement to filter my Parse query. For example if the user selected to filter by Highest rated, in my `queryForTable()` function, I'll put something like:

```
if XXXXXXXXXXXX {

query.orderByDescending("highestRated")

}
```

And I've already created the popover VC and it works.

Hopefully this makes sense...if not please ask more info. The code for my popover VC is below:

```
class SortByViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var sortByTableView: UITableView!

var sortByOptions = ["Date added", "Film name", "Our star rating", "Highest rated", "Lowest rated", "Director's name"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sortByTableView.rowHeight = 44.0

    sortByTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)

    sortByTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sortByOptions.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = sortByTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.sortByOptions[indexPath.row]

    let imageName = UIImage(named: sortByOptions[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView?.image = imageName

    let itemSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    let imageRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height)
    cell.imageView!.image?.drawInRect(imageRect)
    cell.imageView!.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use protocol / Delegates here. Your popviewcontroller will be a tableviewcontroller or will have a tableview. You have to call this controller as popover. Now in popOverController on didselect call the delegate function and pass the option select as an string/Index as per your requirement. This delegate method will be implementated in your viewcontroller, where you can sort and reload the table.

Here is the demo which i have created. You can update the same as per your requirement.

https://github.com/quantumarun/Demos/tree/master/PopOverDemo

In ViewController.swift check for function

```
func sortSelection(selectedItem: Int)
```

This is the delegate function which will be called when you select in Popover. If you require you can pass string as well instead of Int.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply, could you show me in the code how I can add that, as that's where I'm having the issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: This really helped! thanks very much, got it working perfect!